# Append class names depending on mobile or desktop

Tags: javascript

So I've been messing with this little snippet for some time now and I can't figure it out - I want to be able to set the classnames depending on screen size so mobile, desktop.

So the original is:

```
const container = document.createElement('div');
container.className = 'column is-one-third is-flex py-0';
const anchor = document.createElement('a');
```

This works great for an all around solution, but let's say that I want container.className to be different for screen sizes of 768px (mobile) and less?

I tried doing the below but haven't had the luck to get it to work yet:

```
const container = document.createElement('div');
if (window.matchMedia( "(max-width: 768px)" )) {
    container.className = 'column is-half is-flex py-0';
} else {
    container.className = 'column is-one-third is-flex py-0';
}
const anchor = document.createElement('a');
```

All help will be appreciated!

Comment: `let mobile = navigator.userAgent.match(/Mobi/i) ? true : false;` is a better mobile test, since you have no way to know if they really have a mobile device simply based on resolution.

Comment: `window.matchMedia( "(max-width: 768px)" )` returns an object, so it will always return true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using `matchMedia`, you should use the `matches` properties to see whether the screen size fit the media query or not. Check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) out for more info.

```
let mql = window.matchMedia( "(max-width: 768px)" )

if (mql.matches) {
    container.className = 'column is-half is-flex py-0';
} else {
    container.className = 'column is-one-third is-flex py-0';
}
```

Comment: @DevSem By the way, for such kind of condition problem. I usually set a debugger or a ```console.log()``` to see which condition goes wrong. This helps to debug faster.